# Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправил сообщения в лс, пользователя который вел команду?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот мой код:

```py
@client.command()
async def слова(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    member = тут был мой айди
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", colour=0xFFFFFF, description="")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    
    await member.send("asdasd")
```

А ошибка:

> member is a required argument that is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ответ уже будет не актуален, но возможно кому-то поможет.
Вам нужно получить автора сообщения с помощью ctx.author.

```py
@client.command()
async def слова(ctx):
    member = ctx.author # получаем автора сообщения
    embed = discord.Embed(title="1", colour=0xFFFFFF, description="1") #Поля не должны быть пустыми.
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await member.send("asdasd")
```

Вы также можете отправить сообщение напрямую без добавления лишней переменной.

```py
@client.command()
async def слова(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="1", colour=0xFFFFFF, description="1") #Поля не должны быть пустыми.
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.author.send("asdasd")
```

Answer (score 0):

извиняюсь за глупую ошибку с member, надо было написать
`ctx.author.send`, так как мой код вводил кому-то, а этого кому-то не было, а мне надо было чтобы автору, а я писал member, да member.

Answer (score -1):

Ты не указываешь аргумент в команде.
Тебе нужно указать его.
Пример: $hi_to @Юзер
Так же, тебе надо удалить
строку

```py
member = тут был мой айди
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: я уже понял, как сделать и то, что вы написали это бы не решило, мне надо было прописать ctx.author.send и всё, а member когда хочешь, чтоб бот отметил кого-то или когда нет способа сделать author, например on_member_join().